# Jquery. Disable scanning on any input but allow user to type

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jquery-scanner-detection](https://github.com/escaleno-ltda/jQuery-Scanner-Detection):

```
            $(function () {
                 $(document).scannerDetection();
                 $(document).bind('scannerDetectionComplete', function (e, data) {
                 alert("Received from scanner --> " + data.string);
               });
            })
```

**I'd like to know if it's possible to disable scanning on any input but still allow the user to type?**

I know scanning is just a series of keypresses. I've tried a few different ideas to determine the interval between keypresses to e.preventDefault() the input but I'm always left with the first character of the scan result.